# Mostrar UpdateView según usuario en Django

Tags: python, django, update

Hola me gustaría que un usuario solo pueda modificar los registros de una tabla según su nombre de usuario.

el nombre de usuario (user.username) y el cuil (voluntarios.cuil) deben coincidir.

Me pueden ayudar a que muestre la vista de update al usuario donde username=cuil

models.py

```
class voluntarios(models.Model):
    cuil = models.BigIntegerField()
```

view.py

```
class ModificarVoluntario (LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    model = voluntarios
    form_class = voluntariosForm
    template_name = 'voluntariado/formvoluntarios.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('listar_voluntarios')
```

Comment: Ya lo solucionaste? para ayudarte

Comment: Lo solucioné con el metodo get_object y haciendo una query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class ModificarVoluntario (LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    """Presentar formulario al usuario para modificar"""

    model = voluntarios
    form_class = voluntariosForm
    template_name = 'voluntariado/formvoluntarios.html'

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
        u = self.request.user.username
        queryset = voluntarios.objects.filter(cuil=u)
        try:
            obj = queryset.get()
        except queryset.model.DoesNotExist:
            raise Http404("Su usuario no tiene un formulario registrado")
        return obj

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('inicio')
```